# Gitlab CI configuration is invalid for conditional statement

Tags: bash, ubuntu, yaml, gitlab-ci

Why is this line in my gitlab CI configuration invalid? `did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character while scanning an anchor`

```
script:
  - [ ! -z $(docker images -q $IMAGE1) ] && docker tag $IMAGE1 $IMAGE2
```

How should I modify this line?

I need to check if the image exists before creating a tag for that image. If it doesn't exists, this line should be skipped, but the CI should go on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote the command:

```
script:
  - "[ ! -z $(docker images -q $IMAGE1) ] && docker tag $IMAGE1 $IMAGE2"
```

Comment: Why (or when) do I have to quote?